# Sending body with headers - Request npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, npm-request

I am using npm Request module to make a post request. I am able to send headers but not the body.

As per [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#custom-http-headers) they have mentioned the way how to add headers, but not the way how to add headers+body.

Here is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors');
var requestz = require('request');

var makeRequest = function makeRequest(request, response){
        var formData = {
                bulkFileValue: "WyI5MjMyMzE0OTQ3NTYixxxxTciLCI5MjMwNTIyNzM1NzUiLCI5MjMyMTE0OTQ3NTkiLCI5MjMyMTQyODYzNzQiLCI5MjMyMTE0OTQ3Nxxxx0OTQ3NjIiLxxE0OTQ3NjMiLCI5MjMyMTE0OTQ3NjQiLCI5MjMxxQ3NjUiLCI5MjMyMTE0OTQ3NjYiXQ==", 
                applicationVersion: "1.0",
                username: 'axxxz@fxxxxa.pk', password: 'Wxxxxedxxx3'

         }
        var options = {
          url: 'http://newxxxxxapi.fxxxxca.web.pk/UploxxxxxkEx',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'appKey':'dNExxxxxARypxxxxnLG',
            'appId':'2xxxxx7'
          },
          formData: formData
        };

        function callback(error, resp, body) {
          if (!error && resp.statusCode == 200) {
            var info = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(info);
            response.send(info);
          }
        }

        requestz.post(options, callback);

}



exports.processPayroll = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    var corsFn = cors();
    corsFn(request, response, function() {
        makeRequest(request, response);
    })

});
```

In the above code i am trying to send data/body as formData. But i think that is not the right way.

Please help me out with this as body/formData is not receiving on other end.

Comment: If you change the `formData` *key* to `form` in the options object, does it work? You also don't need to explicitly set the content type, the library handles that by itself.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Post it as Answer please :)